# Inserting records into table from json object using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write a program that gets a json object from an api call and then loads that into a database. sqlalchemy keeps throwing the error `AttributeError: 'TextClause' object has no attribute 'implicit_returning'` when I compile `stmt` or try to just execute it on its own.

```
def load_results(self):
      connect = self.engine.connect()

      for ru in self.json_ru:
          counties = ru['counties']
          for county in counties:
              transaction = connect.begin()
              params = {"reportingunitName": ru['reportingunitName'],
                                "geoCode": ru['geocode'],
                                "townsTotal": ru['towns'],
                                "townsReporting": ru['townsReporting'],
                                "cableName": county['cableName'],
                                "unitCount": county['unitCount']
                                }
              stmt = expression.insert('{}.raw_feed'.format(self.state)).values(params)
              compiled_stmt = stmt.compile(self.engine)
              connect.execute(compiled_stmt)
              transaction.commit()
```

Before I had a query I was just feeding into connect.execute, but the strings that were coming in as values were being read as column names, so I tried the above instead. Also using Postgres flavor.